How to do I assign a unique persistent id to every single HTML tag and capture the id of block changed?
I have a use-case where I need to assign a unique and persistent unique id to each HTML tag in my page.
Background:
I have created a block element so everything in the webpage is a <Block /> element now.
The block element is defined like this
export const Block = ({ children, className = "", id = "", ...props }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Clicks working");
  };

  const prevChildrenRef = useRef(children);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevChildrenRef.current !== children) {
      console.log(`Content changed for id ${id}`);
      prevChildrenRef.current = children;
    }
  }, [children, id]);

  console.log(`Rendering Block with ID: ${id}`);

  return (
    <div className={`${className} hover`} id={id} onClick={handleClick} {...props}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

This is how I am using my block element, similarly in the whole page, everything is a Block at the atomic level.
usage:
<Block className="flex flex-col items-start space-y-1 text-start">
      <Block>
        <Block className="text-4xl font-bold">{start.name}</Block>
        <Block className="py-2 text-2xl">{start.headline}</Block>
      </Block>
</Block>

I would want to create a unique and persistent id for each block so even after page refresh, it would remain consistent.
What I have tried:
I tried naming every section's block using recursion, so the top root element will have unique id as the section name, for example here, start, as we go down the children, they will be have the id <parent_id>_1, <parent_id>_2, <parent_id>_1_1 (parent's grandchildren) and so on.
Here is the code.
export const assignIds = (element, idPrefix = prefix) => l{
  let counter = 1;

  const childrenWithIds = React.Children.map(element.props.children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      const newIdPrefix = `${idPrefix}_${counter}`;
      counter++;
      return React.cloneElement(
        child,
        { id: newIdPrefix, key: newIdPrefix },
        assignIds(child, newIdPrefix),
      );
    }
    return child;
  });

  return React.cloneElement(element, { id: idPrefix }, childrenWithIds);
};

While this approach works, the issue I am facing is, when the value of {start.name} or {start.headline} is changed, I only want to capture the id of that block which it is under,and not the parent or grandparent. Right now with my code implementation, it is also triggering the console - console.log(`Content changed for id ${id}`); (in the block) defined inside useEffect for parent as well as grandparents.
Where I need help
Ultimately, what I want is to capture the id of only the block which is being changed, without involving any ancestors so I can dynamically pass the CSS to change its style dynamically.

This is a very odd request. Can you go into more detail about the problem you are trying to solve with this? Expand on "so I can dynamically pass the CSS to change its style dynamically.". Give me an example problem you have that you think this solution would solve.  I can think of several much better ways of tackling this problem of applying css to anything which changes. You are likely chasing an impractical approach. But need to know more about what you ultimately want to do with this.

@adsy P1> Sure and thanks for your time. So imagine my webpage is distributed in 4 sections, lets call them - header, footer, basic details and content. Now each of these will have headings, paragraphs and other usual things which make up to a webpage. What I am trying to achieve is, I have an input dropdown which lets me select colors, other input field lets me enter margin, so what I want user to be able to do is to customize the webpage however they want. You can think like this that I am giving them initial template, but want to give them freedom to change literally anything imaginable.

P2> For example, if user wants heading in the basic details to be bit left shifted, they can easily do it since when they click on the heading, I would set an active id state in react and that sets our active Block. Now, from the typography on sidebar, they can change whatever they want through drop downs and input fields without having them exposed to html code. That's why I want each block to have a unique persistent id, so on clicking it, I can set it as currrent and directly change the styles and things around it. Let me know if you want any further clarifications.

So this would usually be done one of 2 ways (sometimes a mix). (1) via some theme object that lives high up in your app and is provided through context https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context. The core colors, spacing etc would live in this theme object. The styles of the elements would then read from these values (style prop, or something like emotion) and effortlessly rerender when they change. The inputs to change the theme would call some setter from the context.

(2) Have the css connect to CSS variables (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) then simply have the inputs edit the css variables and apply them to some high up parent element. For example. https://epicreact.dev/css-variables/. Lots of libs will make your life easier like css-in-js libs like emotion. To do what you want, you need the concept of "design tokens". You need to abstract the "core" styles. Either way, current approach is, no offence intended, really crazy! :)

Though,i realise you have a unique problem in that you want to be able to do this on a component instance level. So not just change all buttons for example. But this one specific button. This makes things a bit harder. But you could just have the components useId() and then register themselves into the theme conext on mount.

If you need to persist this theme, you'd need a stable ID between hardrefresh. There isnt really a sane for those IDs to be consistent in that way. Your way of counting ancestors would break badly if the page structure changes because of a change you make. 1 renesting would break the whole thing and any dynamic site functionality would also break it. Unless your ok with it being tied to specific content and not persisting if there are content changes.

The reason no code "page builders" that exist can do this is because the structure changes are also managed in those tools. That allows them to keep "ids" consistent as they can track the changes and mutations the user does to alter the page. The only way to achieve that here in a way that wouldn't break the entire site every time a change is made, is to manually assign unique identifiers.

@adsy P1. Thanks for taking all the efforts to answer the problem, highly appreciated. Yes, I actually do not want to change all the buttons(or para, or headings) but want the users to be able to change every single one of them. Regarding your concern on the structure part, the basic structure ie the skeleton wouldnt change, only the attributes would. So, if a para is a child of the div, it would remain the child of the div even after letting users take the control. What I want the users to be able to do is, change the font size or color or some other properties. For one second if I assume...

my hierarchy would work assigning the ids to components, it will still be challenging to not let the ancestors also being tracked, when the child is changed(please check my example). Do you have any idea how can I limit that from happening? So, on change, or click, only the block that's being changed would be tracked, and it wont trigger the parents? Right now my logic tracks the conent of children previously vs after change, so obviously it will also trigger the ancestors, but that I dont really want.

So your refs are currently refs of the react element objects and I dont think these are stable in the way you think they are between renders. Especially since you use cloneElement. At the same time this is difficult to solve at a DOM or mutationobserver level as well. Im not sure I understand the part about needing to detect changes. What will you do in place of the console log? It's probably quite a bit easier if you make whatever action that is idempotent. Have the effect just on [id] with no comparing children. Just make whatever it does safe to repeat.

I understand it is kinda tricky request.I am trying to find the solution for couple days myself. After brainstorming a lot I am even more convinced that if there has to be a way for the solution, it has to be in these lines only. "What will you do in place of the console log?" Well, I will store the id for that block to the store as currentId and then when I let user change margin on sidebars to say 1.5px, I will inject that margin value for that particular active block, so the block will get something like this in className = ml-{leftMargin}, so it will shift to left, margin is just an ex.

It's better clicked for me where your headspace is now. So I think yes, the answer here is the element change detection part is not needed. Having an effect ID is  ok, and that can register it in the "store" (I'm guessing you have some global store or something and the custom values are also in there against the ID). But then the block component itself can simply read the relevant values from the store and apply className in the JSX via concatenation. Unless I'm still missing something, there's no need for the comparing refs of elements.

Maybe you are overthinking the "inject" className part. Can you go into detail a bit more about (a) How you planned to do the "inject" part (it can be done in the JSX of block itself, if the custom styles are in some store Block can read from). (b) What this "store" is. Im assuming its some kind of react-compatible store or  context. If you simply connect Block to the store/context; read the custom styles; merge them in the className of the first div in Block ; then there is no value to detecting the ref'ed element comparison. As the operations would be idempotent cos of VDOM.

as far as I understood your question, you let user modify the css of webpage and keep this css configuration persistent. is this correct?

@adsy @Anon can ya'll delete this conversation. It is distracting and not helpful. What is most helpful is providing some reproducible example of the ancestors getting the unwanted id's. Seems you just need a filter or pass in the right element to assignIds.

Can you please upload an example in stackblitz?

I don't agree it's unhelpful at all. Actually, I think we're on the cusp of it and the additional info on use case is crucial and should probs be edited back into OP.

@adsy Sorry for not being able to get back here due to a major release. To answer your question -
a) I am planning to do injection by identifying the block with id = active id and then changing their properties to what the user enters. I think it would require me to dangerously inject the css classes.
b) The store is a react compatible store, like zustand which I am using.
" If you simply connect Block to the store/context;" the issue with this is - there would be a need to keep track of a lot of block elements, and second is, if i am clicking on a block,... 1/2

how would i stop the parent from changing. I only need the only block changing to be getting triggered.. 2/2

I came accross similar issue when working on a design editor .
Basically you want your user to be able to select any block and set the current selected state as the selected block.
Actually you can achieve that without assiging id to each block. And keep also in mind that useRef and useEffect works really bad together. If you want to listen to any dom element change, prefer to use useCallback

You need to have a parent Context which will provide the select node/block function and also a deselect. Basically:

    const BlockContext = createContext(null);
    const BlockProvider = ({children}) => {
        const [block, setBlock] = useState()
        const selectBlock = (block) = setBlock(block);
        const reset = () => setBlock(undefined);
        return (
            <BlockContext.Provider value={{block, selectBlock, reset}}>
                {children}
            </BlockContext.Provider>
        )
    }
    const useBlock = () => {
        const context = useContext(BlockContext);
        return context;
    }


Second part is you have to create a hook to listen for any change related to your block, why? because when you allow your user to edit whatever about the selected block, the user changes the dom element, not the shallow copy that React compares. so a simple example is:

    const useReference = () => {
        const [node, setNode] = useState();
    
        const ref = useCallback((element) => {
            setNode(element)
        }, []);
    
        return [node, ref];
    }


Now you can combine both in your Block component:


    export const Block = ({ children, className = "", ...props }) => {
        const {block, selectBlock} = useBlock();
        const [node, ref] = useReference();
    
        const handleClick = () => {
          console.log("Clicks working");
          selectBlock(node);
        };
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (block && node) selectBlock(node);
        }, [node]);
      
        return (
          <div {...props} ref={ref} className={`${className} hover`} onClick={handleClick} >
            {children}
          </div>
        );
    };


Conclusion: This way, you will always have an updated version of the selected dom element/Block. I hope this might fit your needs

Here's the updated code:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useContext, createContext } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

// Context to pass down the parent ID
const ParentIdContext = createContext('');

// Function to generate or retrieve a persistent ID
const getPersistentId = (id) => {
  if (!id) {
    const newId = uuidv4();
    localStorage.setItem(newId, newId);
    return newId;
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(id) || id;
};

export const Block = ({ children, className = "", id = "", ...props }) => {
  const parentId = useContext(ParentIdContext);
  const persistentId = getPersistentId(id || `${parentId}_${uuidv4()}`);
  const prevChildrenRef = useRef(children);
  const prevChildrenStringRef = useRef(JSON.stringify(children));

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentChildrenString = JSON.stringify(children);
    if (prevChildrenStringRef.current !== currentChildrenString) {
      console.log(`Content changed for id ${persistentId}`);
      // Here you can add your logic to apply dynamic CSS changes
      prevChildrenRef.current = children;
      prevChildrenStringRef.current = currentChildrenString;
    }
  }, [children, persistentId]);

  console.log(`Rendering Block with ID: ${persistentId}`);

  return (
    <ParentIdContext.Provider value={persistentId}>
      <div className={`${className} hover`} id={persistentId} {...props}>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
          if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
              key: `${persistentId}_${index}`,
              id: `${persistentId}_${index}`,
            });
          }
          return child;
        })}
      </div>
    </ParentIdContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Usage remains the same
// <Block className="flex flex-col items-start space-y-1 text-start">
//   <Block>
//     <Block className="text-4xl font-bold">{start.name}</Block>
//     <Block className="py-2 text-2xl">{start.headline}</Block>
//   </Block>
// </Block>

This approach solves several problems:

IDs are unique and persistent across page refreshes due to localStorage usage.
Only the specific Block that changed will log the change, not its ancestors.
The ID structure maintains a hierarchy (parentId_childIndex), making it easy to understand the structure of your page.

To use this, you don't need to change your existing Block usage. The IDs will be automatically generated and assigned.
To apply dynamic CSS based on changes, you can add your logic in the useEffect hook where we log the change. For example:
useEffect(() => {
  const currentChildrenString = JSON.stringify(children);
  if (prevChildrenStringRef.current !== currentChildrenString) {
    console.log(`Content changed for id ${persistentId}`);
    // Apply dynamic CSS
    document.getElementById(persistentId).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    // Reset after a delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById(persistentId).style.backgroundColor = '';
    }, 2000);
    prevChildrenRef.current = children;
    prevChildrenStringRef.current = currentChildrenString;
  }
}, [children, persistentId]);


Hi. Sorry for getting back late. I will try this out but before that I have slight doubt. When you keep track of initial children and then comparing it with the changed current children,  wont it also get triggered for parents? for example  -
<div id="children>change me   if the "change me" is changed, it will detect the changes, but it will also trigger for parent since its children is also technically changed and not remained the same. So useeffect should also detect changes to parent, no?
Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

To save others the trouble to check: The only (effective) difference of this answer to the original post is the line if (JSON.stringify(initialChildren.current) !== JSON.stringify(children)) {, i.e. the children are strigified for the equality check.
